# If statement output using | operator

Tags: c

I need to know how the output of the if statement is calculated true or false based on the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum designFlags {
    BOLD = 8,
    ITALICS = 9,
    UNDERLINE = 4
};

int main() {

    int myDesign = BOLD & ITALICS;
    printf("%d", myDesign);

    if(BOLD & ITALICS)
       printf("Design is ITALIC");
    else
       printf("Design is not ITALIC");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do your own homework!

Comment: ...just run the code?

Comment: The question doesn't match the code.

Comment: Yeah, there's no `|` operator in sight. This is an abysmal attempt at a question.

Comment: Why the disgusting formatting?

Comment: i want to know why the if statement comes true?

Comment: It is false. Just write that down. You might be lucky as it is 50/50

Comment: You do know that `&` and `|` are *bitwise* operators, not logical? And that everything non-zero is considered true, with only zero being false?

Comment: Any basic C book or tutorial will explain what corresponds to true or false in an `if` statement, as well as basic logical vs bitwise operators. This is not worth a question, nor any answers.

Comment: I keep forgetting that Uni started at the beginning of October. We are at the start of November so students are getting homework where they need to think. Hence these questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first go through any C books for operators.

if(BOLD & ITALICS )

'&' its a bitwise And operator . i.e it operates on bits

```
BOLD    = 8 = 0000 1000
                      &
ITALICS = 9 = 0000 1001  (check the truth table of bitwise & )
-------------------------
            = 0000 1000 =8
```

So if(8) means true so "Design is Italics" gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

As per standard **§6.8.4.1**

> the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal
>   to 0. In the else form, the second substatement is executed if the
>   expression compares equal to 0.

Here the result is `8` a nonzero so if statement is executed.

The bitwise `and` operator is applied between those two enum values resulting in the value of 8.

The name bitwise gives enough hint on how it works. You write down the binary and perform `and` operation bit by bit.

As per standard,**§6.5.10**

> The result of the binary `&` operator is the bitwise AND of the
>   operands (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only if each
>   of the corresponding bits in the converted operands is set).